# $GOPATH/go.mod exists but should not when building docker container, but works if I manually run commands

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, go-redis

I'm building a golang:1.14.2 docker container with go-redis from a Dockerfile.

```
FROM golang:1.14.2

# project setup and install go-redis
RUN mkdir -p /go/delivery && cd /go/delivery && \
    go mod init example.com/delivery && \
    go get github.com/go-redis/redis/v7 

# important to copy to /go/delivery
COPY ./src /go/delivery

RUN ls -la /go/delivery

RUN go install example.com/delivery
ENTRYPOINT ["delivery"]
```

However, when I try to build the container using `docker-compose up --build -d`, I get this error: `$GOPATH/go.mod exists but should not
ERROR: Service 'delivery' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c go get github.com/go-redis/redis/v7' returned a non-zero code: 1`.

However, I can create a docker container using the image from the dockerfile `docker container run -it --rm golang:1.14.2` and then run the exact same commands as in the Dockerfile, and `delivery` does what I expect it to. 
``

Here is deliver.go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/go-redis/redis/v7"
)

func main() {
    // redis client created here... 

    fmt.Println("inside main...")
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I looked up this error message and none of the solutions I've seen worked for me.

EDIT: Here is the compose file:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  ...
  delivery:
    build: ./delivery
    environment:
      - REDIS_PORT=${REDIS_PORT}
      - REDIS_PASS=${REDIS_PASS}
      - QUEUE_NAME-${QUEUE_NAME}
    volumes: 
      - ./logs:/logs
```

Comment: It sounds like something is setting `GOPATH=/go/delivery` and it shouldn't be. It might be a default for that image.

Comment: you should add the compose file as well, as given what you have said, the issue is probably there, and it's probably because of some directory you're mounting .

Comment: Also running `go install example.com/delivery` isn't going to use the local sources, it's going to use the sources from the repo published at `go install example.com/delivery`. To use local sources you want to `cd` to the project and just run `go install`, or better yet, `go build`.

Comment: If this is for distributing/running the app rather than just building it, I'd scrap it altogether. Go applications are self-contained binaries and do not require the toolchain at runtime. A Docker container for *running* the program should just be a base container with the compiled binary copied into it.

Comment: @Adrian would the command to execute the copied binary be something like `CMD ["/bin/bash", "<binary_name>"]`?

Comment: No, `bash` would be for running bash scripts. You'd just run the binary.

Comment: @Adrian every time I would make changes to the source code I would need to rebuild the binary, and then copy it unto the container. I'd like to change the source file and still get a working application

Comment: You want to edit the source and rebuild it inside the container? The typical flow for containers would be to publish a new container for a new version of the application. If you're editing inside the container it defeats most of the purpose of containers; it's not immutable, and it's not scalable.

Comment: @Adrian no I have a git repo that contains code, including `delivery.go` that I copy into the go container in the Dockerfile. I would be able to `docker-compose up` and have new containers whenever I change the source files on my local machine, not in the container

Comment: Then you can just build the binary and compose. If you don't want to run `go build && docker-compose up` you could write a bash script with that as its only contents, but that's literally all there is to it. The only time a Docker container should contain the Go toolchain is if the container is running as a build agent for CI/CD; a container running a service written in Go should just have the Go binary.

Comment: How did u solve that?

Answer (score 16):

I have same problem. You need set **WORKDIR /go/delivery**

Comment: Would appreciate some explanation. Although, it worked.